# Como evito los saltos de linea cuando introduzco un numero?

Tags: java, netbeans

Cuando elijo una opción cualquiera, me pide que introduzca un numero, pero es ahí cuando dicho numero pasa a estar abajo y no sigue. Por ejemplo:

```
Introduzca un numero:  '1
```

Yo deseo que ese numero aparezca ahi y lo que pasa es:

```
Introduzca un numero: (no lo hace acá, salta una línea)
1
```

Este es mi código:

```
package prueba;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prueba 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     int n, num1, num2, resultado;
     Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("1. Sumar");
     System.out.println("2. Restar");
     System.out.println("3. Multiplicar");
     System.out.println("4. Dividir ");
     System.out.println("Elige una opcion del menu: ");
     n=leer.nextInt();

     switch (n)
             {
         case 1:
             System.out.println("ingresa un numero: ");
             num1=leer.nextInt();
             System.out.println("ingresa otro numero: ");
             num2=leer.nextInt();
             System.out.println("El resultado es: "+(num1+num2));
             break;

         case 2:
             System.out.println("ingresa un numero: ");
             num1=leer.nextInt();
             System.out.println("ingresa otro numero: ");
             num2=leer.nextInt();
             System.out.println("El resultado es: "+(num1-num2));
             break;

         case 3:
             System.out.println("ingresa un numero: ");
             num1=leer.nextInt();
             System.out.println("ingresa otro numero: ");
             num2=leer.nextInt();
             System.out.println("El resultado es: "+(num1*num2));
             break;

         case 4:
             System.out.println("ingresa un numero: ");
             num1=leer.nextInt();
             System.out.println("ingresa otro numero: ");
             num2=leer.nextInt();
             System.out.println("El resultado es: "+(num1/num2));
             break;    

         default:
             System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
             break;
             }

    }
}
```

Comment: Solo debes usar `System.out.print()` en vez de `System.out.println`, ya cuando leas el numero haces un salto de linea `System.out.println`

Answer (score 5):

Usa [`System.out.print`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) en lugar de [`System.out.println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) por ejemplo:

```
   ...
   ...
   System.out.print("ingresa un numero: ");
   num1= leer.nextInt();
   System.out.print("ingresa otro numero: ");
   num2=leer.nextInt();
   System.out.print("El resultado es: "+(num1+num2));
   ...
   ...
```

la diferencia entre **[`System.out.print`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html)** y **[`System.out.println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html)** es que el último inserta al final un salto de linea (mueve el cursor a una nueva linea) y `System.out.print` no lo realiza, por ese motivo puedes seguir escribiendo sobre la misma linea.

Aquí un buen artículo:
[Uso de **print** y **println**](https://www.programarya.com/Cursos/Java/Salida-De-Datos)

Answer (score 4):

Deberías de usar `print` en vez de `println`:

```
System.out.println("ingresa un numero: ");
```

debería ser:

```
System.out.print("ingresa un numero: ");
```

para que no te aparezca el número en la siguiente línea.

Realmente la diferencia entre ambos es que `print` te escribirá el texto que le hayas especificado sin un salto de línea por lo tanto el resto de texto que escribas por consola se escribirá en la misma línea.

Por el contrario, `println` introduce el texto con un salto de línea al final y es por eso que los números se te escriben en la línea siguiente.